# bug of loading background picture

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem for the moment. I wrote a very simple website looks like:

[image]

It displays normally. But when i try to refresh it, not often, maybe one time for 10 freshes, the display of the background photo bugged like:

[image]

I'm new to the frontend design and I don't know what happened. Can someone help me? Here is my html and css code, and this bug appears only with chrome, with firefox it works well.

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='login.css') }}">
    <title> Login page :) </title>
</head>

<body>    
  <div id="div_title">
      <span id="title"> Welcome to wentong's website! </span>
      </br>
      <a href="{{ url_for('homepage') }}" id="guestlink">Entrance for guests here :)</a>
  </div>

  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}

  <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method=post>
      <div id = "div_login">
          <span class="label">Username:</span>
          <input class="input" type=text name=username>
          <br/>
          <span class="label">Password: </span>
          <input class="input" type=password name=password>
          <br/>
          <input id="submit" type=submit value=Login style="display:none">
      </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the background CSS:

```
html {
   background: url(images/aurora.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: contain;
   -moz-background-size: contain;
   -o-background-size: contain;
   background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: I think it's just temporary bug. May be you don't worry about that.

Comment: Can you post a link to a page where this occurs?

Comment: @Minalinsky
Seems like title's margin somehow influence to image rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place background image like separate img tag with such css rules:

```
.full-screen-background-image {
  z-index: -999;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

and place it to the very bottom of your layout markup

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
   <img class="full-screen-background-image" src="you-image.jpg" />  
</body>
</html>
```